# Stop skype from running at startup and after I closed it

Tags: windows-10, skype

I am using the UWP skype app.

I know there are more questions like this, but I think the skype app has changed lately and they are no longer relevant.

I'm dying to prevent skype from running in the background because I'm fighting for memory space, every bit counts.

Skype version 8.37.0.98

Application version 14.37.98.0

Windows 10

No other relevant settings that I can find besides this one:
[image]

As you can see after a restart it is still here as suspended:
[image]

And it is not in startup:

[image]

I don't know what else to do to stop this app.

Thanks!

Comment: @Run5k thanks but that question is different, it's using the application not the UWP app

Comment: If you take a close look at the accepted answer within that question, you will see that it does a very thorough job of summarizing what to do with both the desktop application **and** the UWP app. It also gets updated on a regular basis, so yes, it is still relevant.

Comment: @Run5k `Skype UWP users simply need to logoff from within the app. ` that's bs. there has to be another way

Comment: @Run5k but yeah I agree, that question better serves the community and this one is a dupe

Comment: But that answer was actually provided by Microsoft's Skype Community Moderator.  While it may not be ideal, the fact that we dislike it doesn't mean that it isn't right.  We are always glad to help and your frustration is totally understandable, but we try to centralize prominent problems within one canonical question for the benefit of the rest of the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest uninstalling the UWP version of Skype. If you need Skype, however, get the desktop version from https://go.skype.com/windows.desktop.download
as it can easily be disabled from the startup menu and also is more stable (for me at least). Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the best solution I could find.  Interestingly if you don't uninstall it it starts every logon even if you have *never once* opened it since installing Windows.

Comment: didn't know that I can still install it like that. thanks

Comment: is it just me, or it is crazy that a UWP app that you never opened is using 143MB as a suspended process?

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot find anything related to it in Skype's settings, such as "start with windows", or "start when the machine starts up", then you can manually disable it using the "msconfig" tool. Simply search for it in Windows, launch it and its last page should list you the items that are automatically started when your computer starts. Disable Skype along with other crapwear that might be there. 
Tip: The most recent windows displays a link there instead of the startup tab, saying that this has moved to the Task Manager, just click it and do the same thing in the task manager.

Comment: This is not how the built in UWP apps work.  You can also see from the picture of Task Manager in the question that it isn't there.